# How can file writes with NodeJS on Docker be inconsistent?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, docker

A while back I've created some feed fetching & processing scripts with NodeJS for an application I'm working on. I've been running this script on my local machine (OSX) manually for a while and momentarily I'm working on having a job do this. I figured I'd go with a Docker droplet ($5/mo) on Digital ocean. I've created a Dockerfile with NodeJS (9), cron and everything I think I need. Everything works fine on my local machine when I build and run the docker container.

However, when I deploy it to Digital Ocean there seems to be different behaviour from running it locally. Exactly the thing I wanted to prevent using Docker. I have a main shell script that calls 8 different node scripts sequentially. On Digital Ocean it seems that some NodeJS-scripts exit prematurely. So they haven't finished yet but the mail shell script continues with the next NodeJS script. An example:

```
 execute() {
    const outputPath = path.join(this._feedDir, this._outputFile);
    return createDirIfNotExists(this._feedDir, this._log)
        .then(() => this._doRequests())
        .then(requestData => this._writeFile(outputPath, JSON.stringify({requests: requestData.map(data => JSON.parse(data))}), this._log))
 }
```

When running the code:

1. Script does create the dir
2. Script does do all the requests to external sources (and accumulates the data)
3. Script sometimes write the data to file, and sometimes not. Without any error code.
4. Main (shell) script always picks up after that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: i don't believe its an problem with the machine its running on, i think the way you are trying to write to file after the response has arrived, if 10000 requests are triggered and all call writeFile, things gonna get slow.. try working with `async.queue` and or `async` module in general at least when the requests complete the write could be async'd or just write to an stream, db, etc..

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Unfortunately there is only one write being done. The requests responses are accumulated and written to file in one chunk. Next to this example I have more situations where a single write fails. Rewriting it with streams or a db is a possibility but still a long shot if I don't know why it fails.

Comment: Try debugging it step by step with some watchers to see what is going on, not saying debug it for 1000+ requests, just try debugging with some data that you expect it to fail and some that you don't. Also produce more output so you know what's happening.

Comment: I've tried to eliminate the shell script and add all the steps in one big JS script and chain them through Promises. No I get a clear 'Killed' error logged by Digital Ocean. It seems there are some memory limits while processing the feeds. I'll investigate further. Thanks.